# Getting the index of the selected row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app where a user clicks a row in a TableViewController and then on another view controller, it displays some information. Right now the information only displays for the objectAtIndex: 0. I want it so that I can get the object for the row the user selects.

TableViewController:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSManagedObjectModel *playerModel = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ vs %@", [playerModel valueForKey:@"player1"], [playerModel valueForKey: @"player2"]]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[playerModel valueForKey:@"date"]];

return cell;
```

ViewController:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Match"];

self.playersArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


NSManagedObjectModel *playerModel = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex: 0];

UILabel *location = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 300, 20)];
[location setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Games: %@", [playerModel valueForKey:@"location"]]];
[self.view addSubview:location];
```

The TableViewController works fine but as I said above, only the objectAtIndex: 0 shows above.

Comment: [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row

Comment: thx but how can I have that as an integer. I tried: NSInteger *row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row but it tells me that it has a problem initalizing NSInteger

Comment: NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row; // NSInteger *row is a pointer to an integer, not the integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your other ViewController can't access the `tableView` of the TableViewController directly in your implementation (i suppose), you have to actually transfer your model object to your ViewController. How depends on your implementation, i.e. whether you are using storyboards or not.

In any case I'd advice to define a public property for ViewController for the `NSManagedObject` you want to transfer.

If your using storyboards you can set this property in `prepareForSegue:`, if your not using storyboards then before presenting the ViewController set this property to your model object.

Comment: actaully all 3 answers helped, but this one helped me the most

Comment: awesome, glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the selected index and get the row from it:

```
[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of handling this.  You can setup a UITableView delegate, and implement `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` or you can call the UITableView method `[myTableVie indexPathForSelectedRow]`